# Which is good user experience while deleting an item from list view

Tags: mobile, lean-ux

While developing a mobile app and working on listview I found two patterns to delete an item from listView which are mentioned below:

1. Using a checkbox:

   Use a checkbox in each listview item and delete those items which are checked as gmail mobile app does.

   [image]
2. Tap/long tap on listview item:

   Tap or long tap event on listview item will open context action menu as can be seen in below pictures.

   [image]
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best user experience would be to combine them, along with adding another feature:

- Single tap on item checks the box for that item.
- Long tap on item checks the box and brings up context menu.
- The **end-all-be-all** is that you need an option to **Select / Deselect All** for multi-item actions.

Answer (score 4):

It is always advisable to use the native gestures for performing basic functions like move, delete, etc.

I gather from your screenshots that yours is an iOS app.

Delete in iOS is available in the following forms-

For bulk delete (Depending on what are the different options available to the user):
[image]

OR

[image]

For single delete-
[image]

Comment: I would say multiple selection on long hold and the option to preform the action.

Comment: @equerambug, that is the interaction style on Android and Windows apps. Native iOS apps don't use this style.

Answer (score 0):

I like the gmail UI more for performing actions on list items.

As per the design, provide a circle containing some identifier for the list item. On tap, it selects the item.

Providing checkbox shows a control which may not be used at all and therefore is irrelevant to the user.

Providing options after long press is also not desirable, because if you are making the app for the web, the user may not know that the menu will come after long press.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you delete a list item, you show some native animation for removing an element from the list. Also, notify the user that he/she has deleted an item in the form of a SnackBar(Android specific) and provide an option to undo it. That should cover the basic UX for this task.

Comment: Nice explanation